# how to configure BIOS settings while installing ps2 emulator

Tags: bios, emulation

i got this error statement while installing the ps2 emulator it says to configure BIOS  how can i get it done 
[image]

Comment: This is explained in the pcsx2 readme and on the forums, you must use bios dumped from the PS2, select it from a folder on your hard drive. For example, mine is called SCPH-70012_BIOS_V12_USA_200. Note however, that it might be considered illegal in some countries to download the PS2 BIOS if you don't own an actual PS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to find a valid BIOS image of a PS2 on the Internet. It has nothing to do with your computer's BIOS image, however, it looks like there is a file [here](http://www.theisozone.com/downloads/playstation/emulators/playstation-2-bios-pack/) for download that should work. Just follow its instructions to extract it and you should be ready to go.

Comment: i am not getting it i have downloaded the file and have extracted it but still i can type any thing or drag and drop anything in the box which says to select the bios rom

Comment: its not working folks